# Word for someone who doesn't know any latest trends?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for someone who doesn't know any new trends? The things that everyone talks about.

For example, someone who doesn't know the new popular movie star or TV show that everyone is crazy about at the time.

Someone who'd often hear, "How could you not know this? Everyone is doing it / has it these days."

I can think of "being shut off from the world", but I wonder if there's a name for someone like that.

Answer (score 3):

You could say that person is **"living under a rock"**. It's an idiom that describes someone being unaware of notable events.

e.g. "You've never heard of instagram? Have you been living under a rock?"

Answer (score 0):

"old-fashioned" is quite popular. Edited, example: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/old-fashioned Best greetings

Comment: Please edit your answer to include a dictionary definition of "old-fashioned" plus a link to the online source.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of person is known as *nonconformist* (or perhaps *maverick*)

***Nonconformist*** is defined by Lexico as:

> a person who does not conform to prevailing ideas or practices in their behaviour or views.

Answer (score 0):

I've often heard and used the term "hermit"; the intended meaning is the same as "living under a rock". Borrowing from the "living under a rock" answer, you'd phrase it like:

```
"You've never heard of instagram? Are you some kind of hermit?"
```

"Hermit"'s original meaning is rather more specific (it's a person who has intentionally separated from all human company, often for religious reasons), but it does directly describe living apart from society, and has been expanded to include hermit-like outcomes such as being unaware of current events or pop culture or the like.